# How to get a list which is a value of a dictionary by a value from the list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following dictionary :

```
d = {'1' : [1, 2, 3, 4], '2' : [10, 20, 30, 40]}
```

How do I get the corresponding key I'm searching by a value from one of the lists?
Let's say I want key '1' if I'm looking for value 3 or key '2' if I'm looking for value 10.

Comment: What if more than one keys are matched?

Comment: It's not the case. Each key represents an <activity_id> which is unique in the dictionary.

Comment: @Binary: keys are always unique in a dictionary. What matters is if the *values in the lists* are unique.

Comment: For your next questions, you may want to read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 5):

You can reverse the dictionary into this structure to do that kind of lookup:

```
reverse_d = {
    1: '1',
    2: '1',
    3: '1',
    4: '1',
    10: '2',
    …
}
```

which can be built by looping over each value of each key:

```
reverse_d = {}

for key, values in d.items():
    for value in values:
        reverse_d[value] = key
```

or more concisely as a dict comprehension:

```
reverse_d = {value: key for key, values in d.items() for value in values}
```

Lookups are straightforward now!

```
k = reverse_d[30]
# k = '2'
```

This only offers better performance than searching through the whole original dictionary if you do multiple lookups, though.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a generator expression with a filtering condition, like this

```
>>> def get_key(d, search_value):
...     return next(key for key, values in d.items() if search_value in values)
...
>>> get_key(d, 10)
'2'
>>> get_key(d, 2)
'1'
```

If none of the keys contain the value being searched for, `None` will be returned.

```
>>> get_key(d, 22)
None
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my first time to answer question. How about this method?

```
def get_key(d,search_value):
        res = []
        for v in d.items():
                if search_value in v[1]:
                        res.append(v[0])
        return res

>>> D = {'a':[2,2,3,4,5],'b':[5,6,7,8,9]}
>>> getkey.get_key(D,2)
['a']
>>> getkey.get_key(D,9)
['b']
>>> getkey.get_key(D,5)
['a', 'b']
```